# How to check if a module exists in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm using [xdg-menu-to-awesome-wm](https://github.com/chouilleur/xdg-menu-to-awesome-wm) to [generate a Lua file](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/ccc39fe2a584242933e074cccb921b50ed7193c0/scripts/cleanup.sh#L74-L83) containing the GNOME menu, for [inclusion](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/3666e0033922d462bba2cab413147540dc7f87d5/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L11) in Awesome WM. Since the generator script may not be installed, I need some way for Lua to only `require` the `menu` module *if it exists*.

I don't want to go looking through file names, since it could be anywhere in `package.path`. One option would be to ignore the exception created when the module does not exist, but I'd rather not ignore any *other* exceptions - I *do* want to know if the module contains any syntax or other errors. The [reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) unfortunately doesn't specify which exceptions can be generated, so I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Just had this issue today, kind of appalled at how many people in the answers section did not seem to realize that a module not being found is not the same thing as the module existing but having syntax errors, or (worse yet) requiring modules of their own which themselves do not exist or have syntax errors. finnw's answer is just what I needed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need to distinguish between a missing module and a syntax error, you can directly access the searcher functions in `package.searchers`.

These functions will:

- Return a loader function if successful
- Return a string if the module is not found
- Throw an error if there is a syntax error

So what you can do is mimic the way `require` searches for a module, calling each searcher in turn until one of them returns a function.  Unlike `require`, we need not throw an error if the module is not found, i.e. if every searcher function returns a string.

```
function isModuleAvailable(name)
  if package.loaded[name] then
    return true
  else
    for _, searcher in ipairs(package.searchers or package.loaders) do
      local loader = searcher(name)
      if type(loader) == 'function' then
        package.preload[name] = loader
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: Test results with `if isModuleAvailable("menu") then require("menu") end`: Crashes if `menu` contains a syntax error, succeeds if it's missing or correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Look, I had the same problem with 'luafilesystem' module, I worked it out like this,

```
local haslfs,lfs = pcall(require,"lfs")
if haslfs then
  configLines["PROJECT_HOME"] = lfs.currentdir()
else
  configLines["PROJECT_HOME"] = prompt("Project path > ")
end
```

'lfs' here is the module handle . And pcall is used to know if the module is really loaded without propagating the error.

Answer (score 6):

What I do is wrap the require in a pcall so that the module is loaded and a fail to load can be caught.  There is a fully worked function which I use to download and install the missing modules from our servers here: 
http://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:code_snippets:module_require_with_load

```
function loadrequire(module)
    local function requiref(module)
        require(module)
    end
    res = pcall(requiref,module)
    if not(res) then
        -- Do Stuff when no module
    end
end
loadrequire('menu')
```

Comment: That looks nice; will try it soon. Nit: Is it just me, or is the indentation inconsistent?

Comment: why do you create a local inner function when you could just do `res = pcall(require, module)`?

Comment: 10b0 - mainly because I typed some and pasted the rest.  Mike To be honest I can't remember,  I think I called it from a couple of places in some plugins.

Comment: This doesn't propagate syntax errors - there's just a boolean result with no indication of what went wrong - so it's actually not what I need.

Comment: @DreamEater That's not what I asked. It's just a very common readability factor.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple `want` function for optional imports.

```
-- Optional require. Example:                                             
--     myMod, err = want'myMod'                                           
--     if not myMod then print(err) end                                   
local function want(name)                                                 
  local out; if xpcall(                         
      function()  out = require(name) end,           
      function(e) out = e end)
  then return out          -- success                                     
  else return nil, out end -- error                                       
end
```

> LICENSE: This code is in the public domain